# How configure the QT addin for Visual studio 2013

Tags: qt, installation

Hy i really need help -_-
i've download the latest QT version (5.7) and i've found the right addin installer but now in visual in the QT option I need to give him a path but WHAT HE NEED?? i don't understand :'(

Answer (score 0):

You need to point the Qt Addin plugin to the Qt path for your build target. For example C:/Qt/5.6/msvc2015_64 for x64 architectures or C:/5.6/msvc2015 for x86 architectures if using msvc2015.